# RESTful interface to get Kibana Visualization or Dashboard URL's

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

Using the elastic REST API and the JSON structure of a particular visualization i have loaded(imported) my charts(visualization)in ".kibana" index .The same is shown in list of visualizations stored in kibana UI .But instead of coming to the UI is there a way to get the URL or the shareable iframe link of this newly created visualization through some rest api .
In short is there a complete REST based flow to create a visualization and retrieve its shareable URL so it can be embedded at required place .

Comment: I don't think there is, but there are [some](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/7899) [efforts](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/15023) being made in order to make the shared dashboards easier to use, namely the latter which would provide a way to define custom short URLs that would probably solve your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reference links Val.My primary concern is not the length of the URL its just the way to fetch those URL.I want to avoid going into the "share" option in visualization and still be able to fetch the  URL (iframe/link) through the REST api directly .

Comment: Yes, but if you can define the URL yourself like in the second link I shared, then you don't need to fetch it at all.

Comment: This one seems more like a open issue.Human readable or customized URL dont seem to be a reality yet as per the second link suggests. !!

Comment: Yes, but that was to hint at the fact that something was coming

Comment: Hope it comes really soon !! Thanks for it and any further update if available would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796815/index-id-identification-in-elasticsearch-kibana-visualization

Also it would be helpful if u can answer the above mentioned question.Thanks in advance :)