# Index ID identification in Elasticsearch/Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
"kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
          "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"4eb9f840-3969-11e8-ae19-552e148747c3\",\"filter\":[],\"query\":{\"language\":\"lucene\",\"query\":\"\"}}"
        }
```

The above mentioned snippet is a exported JSON of a Kibana visualization. Without exporting this json is there a direct way to get this 
`\"index\":\"4eb9f840-3969-11e8-ae19-552e148747c3\` index id.
And if i am not wrong this is supposed to be the index id as its common across visualization with same index.

Comment: It's the ID of the index-pattern that is used for that viz. You can find them with `GET .kibana/_search?q=type:index-pattern`

Comment: Thanks Val this totally helps me in getting the index ID but I guess its just the top few results(10) that get displayed here on this GET request.I need a specific index ID to be returned for the index name of my choice but in the set of 10 indices with their ID I unfortunately did not get the one i really intended to find.What parameter could I pass to fetch just the index ID of the particular index name that I need.

Comment: You can try to add `&size=100` to return all index patterns and optionally add `&q=index-pattern.title:indexname` in order to search for a specific index pattern

Comment: Awesome .Thanks a lot. You are no less than a Knight In Shining Armour for me !!

Comment: And just in case you can help with identifying even the viz ID a a specific viz through its name via GET request I would be really grateful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, you can retrieve all index patterns using this query

```
GET .kibana/_search?q=type:index-pattern&size=100
```

Additionally, you can retrieve a specific set of index pattern given its name using

```
GET .kibana/_search?q=type:index-pattern%20AND%20index-pattern.title:indexname
```

Similarly, regarding visualizations, you can retrieve one by name using

```
GET .kibana/_search?q=type:visualization%20AND%20visualization.title:vizname
```

Comment: Just a small input needed here.The .kibana index can only fetch the indices that are available in Kibana but not the ones in elasticsearch .Is there a way to get the index ID with which its stored in elasticsearch because the above query would fail until i create the index manually in kibana.

Comment: In Kibana, you don't define any index, you define an "index pattern", which can be comprised of many ES "indices".

Comment: Okay, I get that.Actually I have created an index in ES but have not created its index-pattern in Kibana.In order to create a viz of that index I need its index pattern(except in timelions) which I guess could not be retrieved until I create the index-pattern manually.Is that right?Can I not create viz straight from the ES index name?

Comment: In Kibana you need to create an index pattern in order to create viz on top of them, except in Timelion as you mentioned.

Comment: Okay great.Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: Is there API based method to create an index pattern in Kibana if its index is present in ES? @Val

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question, so we don' cram too much into this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913563/is-there-api-based-method-to-create-an-index-pattern-in-kibana-if-its-index-is-p

Comment: @ Val Can you please help me with the following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632917/elasticsearch-clustering-two-ubuntu-based-systems