# How to get the description of a Kibana index pattern via command line?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, kibana

To get the structure of an Elasticsearch **index** via CLI, we can do:

```
curl -u myuser:p4ssw0rd -XGET "https://myeshost:9200/myindexname"
```

Is there a way to get the structure (or other information) about a Kibana **index pattern**, or get the list of all Kibana index patterns that have been created? I haven't found information about this on the documentation.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913869/4604579

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, this seems a perfectly valid question to me.  Suggestions to improve the question (or explanations why, for some, this is a bad question) are genuinely welcome.

Comment: See my linked answer

Comment: @Val Thanks, that's interesting (answer upvoted) but I don't see how I can apply it to my question.

Comment: using `GET .kibana/_search?q=type:"index-pattern"`

Comment: Thanks, this works but only returns a few index patterns.  Do you know why it is so?  BTW, you might want to write it as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to retrieve all Kibana index-patterns using the command below:

```
GET .kibana/_search?size=100&q=type:"index-pattern"
```

Note: if you have more than 100 index-patterns, you might want to increase the size.

Answer (score 0):

Using the functions _stats or _settings:

```
curl -u myuser:p4ssw0rd -XGET "https://myeshost:9200/myindexname/_stats"
curl -u myuser:p4ssw0rd -XGET "https://myeshost:9200/myindexname/_settings"
```

Reference:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-stats.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-get-settings.html

Comment: Thanks, but this gets information about Elasticsearch indexes, not about Kibana index patterns.